# Rummikub, replacing a joker

Tags: rummikub

When replacing a joker from the board [the rules](https://tesera.ru/images/items/784463/Rummikub_Rules.pdf) state I must replace the joker gained from the board with 2 tiles from my hand.

> A joker that has been replaced must be used in the player's same turn with 2 or more tiles from his rack to make a new set

My opponent interprets this meaning that I can only use the tiles from your hand. For example J,4,5 or J,6,6. Though I agree that I must use at least 2 tiles from my hand I find nothing that prohibits me from using another tile from the board along with the joker and the 2 tiles from my hand.  For example I replaced a Joker from board, a 9+12 from my hand, and an 11 from another run to create the following. 9,J,11,12.  My opponent thinks this is an illegal move.

Is this move legal ?

Comment: Primarily it depends on which ruleset you're using. Pick your rule and stick with that. (My vote is "yes" you can use other tiles from the table with your two from hand and a joker.)